# serialport.DataToRead increasing when using telemetry radio

Tags: c#

**Background**

Im building a rc aeroplane telemetry system. There are 2 telemetry radios that transmit data and plugs into a pc via usb serial port.

**The problem**

After lots of diagnosis I discovered that serialport.datatoread is increasing at a rapid rate so its in the throusands after a few seconds, making my program slow and unusabale. I cannot understand why this is as the readline and while loop should clear out the data?#

Whats also strange is this issue doesnt happen if i use a direct serial connection to the aeroplane (FTDI programer) sending the same data. It also ony happens on some devices.

This is my code. I dont understand where the problem is coming from and im running out of troubleshooting ideas.

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) //We've recieve some new data
    {

        // get the data from the port
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { DebugLog.Inlines.Add(SP.BytesToRead.ToString() + "\r\n"); });
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { SV.ScrollToEnd(); });
            data = SP.ReadLine();
            
            //decode the incoming data
            try
            {
                switch (data.Substring(0, 1))
                {
                    case "R":
                        PFD.Roll = float.Parse(data.Substring(1)) / 10;
                        break;
                    case "P":
                        PFD.Pitch = float.Parse(data.Substring(1)) / 10;
                        break;
                    case "H":
                        PFD.Heading = float.Parse(data.Substring(1)) / 10;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        PFD.Speed = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "A":
                        PFD.Altitude = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        PFD.FD_R = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "p":
                        PFD.FD_P = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "M":
                        if (int.Parse(data.Substring(1)) == 1)
                        { Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusBox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black; FlightStatus = "Autolevel"; }); }
                        else if (int.Parse(data.Substring(1)) == 0) { this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusBox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black; FlightStatus = "ManualFlight"; }); }
                        break;
                    case "V":
                        BattVolt = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show(data);
                        break;

                }

            }
            catch { MessageBox.Show(data); }
            if (Writer != null)
            {
                Writer.WriteLine((DateTime.Now.Ticks - timeoffset).ToString() + "|" + data);
            }

    }

    private void ConnectDisconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // connect button has been pressed
    {
        if (PortsList.SelectedValue != null && SP.IsOpen == false) // connect the port
        {
            SP.PortName = PortsList.SelectedValue.ToString();
            SP.Parity = Parity.None;
            SP.DataBits = 8;
            SP.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            SP.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            //SP.ReadTimeout = timeout;
            SP.DtrEnable = true;
            SP.RtsEnable = true;
            SP.Open();
            ConnectDisconnect.Content = "Disconnect";
            DebugLog.Inlines.Add("Connected to " + SP.PortName + "\n");
            SP.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
        else if (SP.IsOpen)//disconnect the port
        {
            SP.WriteLine("Bye");
            SP.Close();
            if (Writer != null)
            {
                Writer.Close();
            }
            Writer = null;
            ConnectDisconnect.Content = "Connect";
            DebugLog.Inlines.Add("Diconnected " + SP.PortName + "\n");
            FlightStatus = "Not connected";
            StatusBox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Update #1

This sort of works, is this the right idea?

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) //We've recieve some new data
    {
        //this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { DebugLog.Inlines.Add("datarecieved"); SV.ScrollToEnd(); });
        // get the data from the port
        //do
        //{


        string incoming = "";

        if (Unfin != "")
        {
            incoming = Unfin;
        }
        Unfin = "";

        incoming += SP.ReadExisting();

        string[] lines = incoming.Split('\n');

        if (lines[lines.Count() - 1].Length > 0)
        {
            if (!lines[lines.Count() - 1].Substring(lines[lines.Count() - 1].Length - 1, 1).Equals('\n')) ;
            {
                Unfin = lines[lines.Count() - 1];

            }
        }

        foreach (string data in lines)
        {
            //decode the incoming data
            try
            {
                switch (data.Substring(0, 1))
                {
                    case "R":
                        PFD.Roll = float.Parse(data.Substring(1)) / 10;
                        break;
                    case "P":
                        PFD.Pitch = float.Parse(data.Substring(1)) / 10;
                        break;
                    case "H":
                        PFD.Heading = float.Parse(data.Substring(1)) / 10;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        PFD.Speed = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "A":
                        PFD.Altitude = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        PFD.FD_R = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "p":
                        PFD.FD_P = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    case "M":
                        if (int.Parse(data.Substring(1)) == 1)
                        { Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusBox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black; FlightStatus = "Autolevel"; }); }
                        else if (int.Parse(data.Substring(1)) == 0) { this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusBox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black; FlightStatus = "ManualFlight"; }); }
                        break;
                    case "V":
                        BattVolt = float.Parse(data.Substring(1));
                        break;
                    default:
                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { DebugLog.Inlines.Add(data + "\r\n"); });
                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { SV.ScrollToEnd(); });
                        break;

                }

            }
            catch
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { DebugLog.Inlines.Add(data + "\r\n"); });
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { SV.ScrollToEnd(); });
            }
            if (Writer != null)
            {
                Writer.WriteLine((DateTime.Now.Ticks - timeoffset).ToString() + "|" + data);
            }

        }
        //}
        //while (data != "");
    }
```

Comment: You are only reading one line per event.  If there's more than one line of data waiting for you, you will read the first one and leave the others in the buffer.  When more data arrives, you'll read an old line and all the new data will accumulate.

Comment: Your code is also broken if less than one entire line of data arrives at a time, because the first part of the line will trigger DataReceived in one thread which calls `ReadLine`, and the second part will trigger another DataReceived event, so now you have two threads both doing ReadLine calls on the same serial port at the same time which is a very bad idea.

Comment: Data may not come in one chunk and the beginning of each line may not aligned to the beginning of data.  So these two lines need to be modified :            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { SV.ScrollToEnd(); });
            data = SP.ReadLine();  If you get a piece of a line you have to combine with the next read.

Comment: Solution: [Throw away the DataReceived event](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)  It makes wrong logic easy and correct logic harder.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ben, that seems to be what i need. I read you article and i sort of get it but i am unsure how i can use your example to get a 'line' of data? Thanks for the help

Comment: @GeorgeGohl: You have to reassemble and split apart (at newlines) the data as it comes in.  Which was also required on your existing code (see jdweng's comment above) you just weren't doing it.  Make sure you handle the case where more than one newline is found in an incoming data buffer!

Comment: @Ben, I tried initially to put the read code inside a do { data = read line} while(data != ""); is that a totally wrong approach?

Comment: You can definitely hide the fragment reassembly code in an async function so that your main code can look like that `while ((data = await ReadNextMessage()) != null) { /* process data */}`  The fragment reassembly will have to do some FIFO queuing though.

Comment: [This article of mine](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/reading-lines-serial-port) shows how to do it.  Unfortunately our blog software ate the nice diagrams I had explaining it visually.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, but When i tried to copy the class i got loads of errors? am i doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ben see latest code

Comment: It is those Invoke() calls that bog down the UI thread, scrolling and repainting are expensive operations.  Do them hundreds of times per second and you'll certainly notice.  Not in the least by having nothing useful but a blur to look at.  That isn't useful, so best to just not it.  The "sort of works" version works better because it doesn't Invoke() as much.  No need to compromise the serial port code, that wasn't the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: The serial code absolutely was a problem.  One way to reduce the number of Invoke calls is to use C# multicast delegate feature to collect all the actions into a single Action (or MethodInvoker) delegate, and then pass that to Invoke once.  Or use `await BaseStream.ReadAsync` to process the data from the UI thread and then no cross-thread calls are required at all.